# Google Sheets Formula to show a fee total within a range of dollar amounts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, logical-operators

Current Portfolio Total
37250125

```
User 1 Fees     
0- $5mm 0.65%   32500
$5mm -10mm  0.45%   0
$10mm-25mm  0.35%   0
$25mm-50mm  0.30%   55125.5625
$50mm+  0.20%   0
        
User 1 Total Fees       87625.5625
        
User 2 Fees     
0-$3mm  0.50%   15000
$3mm-5mm    0.36%   0
$5mm-15mm   0.25%   0
$15mm-25mm  0.17%   0
$25mm+  0.13%   0
```

I have tried nesting the formulas IF and AND. I do not use the formulas enough to understand where my logical expression is breaking down. I need to show the value for each fee created within each range of portfolio size. If the portfolio is not large enough to necessitate a fee, it should return zero. If the fee does not take up the entire band, it should return the partial charge.

Comment: Hi! Can you share a minimum reproducible sample, where we can see your data and also your expected results?

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do. You provided a portfolio valuation, some data for User1 fees (including a total of $87,625.5625, and data for user2 fees (with no total). It's is messy and there is no simple explanation of the outcome you want to reach. The basis for calculating fees is not clear. Would you please explain how what the table for each user means, how each user calculates portfolio fees, and the calculated result that you want to reach.